# Conversion of string array to number array in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have the following string

```
salesdata=[[0],[0],[0.767],[1.366],[2.003],[15.128],[32.766],[57.225],[0],[0],[0],[0]];
```

I want to convert it to an integer array with the same format of brackets to pass as highcharts input. I tried this

```
var data=salesdata.split(",");
```

Comment: I can see them as integer array only

Comment: is `salesdata` string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use JSON.parse() to convert that string array to actual array type.

```
console.log(JSON.parse(salesdata))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `eval()` to convert that string array to actual array type. But note that `eval()` is highly discouraged to use in the code.

```js
var salesdata=`[[0],[0],[0.767],[1.366],[2.003],[15.128],[32.766],[57.225],[0],[0],[0],[0]]`;
console.log(eval(salesdata));
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your salesdata is of the below format:

```
    var salesdata='[[0],[0],[0.767],[1.366],[2.003],[15.128],[32.766],[57.225],[0],[0],[0],[0]]';
```

You can convert it to integer using,

```
    var salesdata_array = JSON.parse(salesdata);
    console.log(salesdata_array[0])
```